# How to detect if an object's field is readonly or read/write, using reflection?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a class like

```
class A
{
    public string Field1 = "Field1 initial";
    public readonly string Field2 = "Field2 initial";
}
```

how to detect if a field is readonly or not?

for instance with this code

```
namespace Example
{
    class A
    {
        public string Field1 = "Field1 initial";
        public readonly string Field2 = "Field2 initial";
    }

    class Program
    {
        static object GetObj()
        {
            A a = new A();
            return a;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = GetObj();
            var fieldNames=obj.GetType().GetFields();
            foreach (var fieldName in fieldNames)
                Console.WriteLine(fieldName.Name);
       }
    }
}
```

I can retrieve field's names, but not the atribute `readonly`.

Even if I use the overloaded `GetFields(...)` that takes na enumeration attribute, I can't retrieve this information.

How can I detect if a class' field is readonly or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you're looking for is called [`IsInitOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isinitonly(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `FieldInfo.IsInitOnly` Property
>
> Gets a value indicating whether the field can only be set in the body of the constructor.

Comment: You are fast! Thanks.

Comment: The ''bigbrother'' says I cannot accept an answer now! I have to wait 2 minutes...

Comment: ''georgeorwell'' came to rescue me!